# How do you get a rectangle drawing to lengthen the more you type in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, drawing

In this program when the user types more text I want the rectangle to automatically get longer when the user types to keep the letters inside of the rectangle. However, it doesn't update the rectangle when the text gets longer. How do I fix this?

```
from pygame import *

init()
screen = display.set_mode((800, 600))

name_font = font.Font(None, 32)
name_text = ''

class Rectangle:


    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.input_rect = Rect(x, y, 140, 32)
        self.text_surface = name_font.render(name_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
        color = Color('lightskyblue3')
        draw.rect(screen, color, self.input_rect, 2)
        self.input_rect.w = self.text_surface.get_width() + 10
        screen.blit(self.text_surface, (self.input_rect.x + 5, self.input_rect.y + 5))

def naming():
    global name_text
    if events.type == KEYDOWN:
        if keys[K_BACKSPACE]:
            name_text = name_text[:-1]
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            rect_1 = Rectangle(200, 200)
        else:
            name_text += events.unicode

while True:
    rect_1 = Rectangle(200, 200)
    for events in event.get():
        keys = key.get_pressed()
        naming()
        if events.type == QUIT:
            quit()
    display.update()
    time.delay(1)
```

Comment: You have to redraw the rectangle.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Rectangle.text_surface` is a PyGame Surface.  So you can easily get  the precise width of the bounding box by simply calling `self.text_surface.get_width()`.

But you start the size of the border-rect at 140, so this size has to be the maximum of 140 *or* whatever the new (longer) width is.  Another problem is that when the rectangle re-sizes, the old rectangle is left behind.  So whenever we now re-draw the rectangle, it erases the background to black.

[image: demo]

This is all pretty easily encapsulated into the exiting `__init__()`:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.text_surface = name_font.render(name_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
    rect_width = max( 140, 10 + self.text_surface.get_width() )    # Adjust the width
    color = Color('lightskyblue3')
    self.input_rect = Rect(x, y, rect_width, 32)                   # Use new width (if any)
    draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0) , self.input_rect, 0)                # Erase any existing rect
    draw.rect(screen, color, self.input_rect, 2)
    self.input_rect.w = self.text_surface.get_width() + 10
    screen.blit(self.text_surface, (self.input_rect.x + 5, self.input_rect.y + 5))
```